# How do I run 1 instance of rsync / rclone script using flock as a cron job?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, backup

I'm trying to run only one instance of my back up script as a cron job.
I know I can do it with a function that checks if the process is running:

```
if pgrep -x rclone >/dev/null
then
    # rclone is still running, backup is not done yet, exit.
    exit
else
    # rclone is not running.
    # start backup.
    /path/to/rclone/script.sh  
fi
```

But after some research, I found out `flock` should be used instead of looking for process ID, in `crontab -e`, in this case, run the script every 30 minutes:
`*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /var/lock/myjob.lock /path/to/rclone/script.sh`

Running the command above **requires sudo**. Therefore, the script asks for sudo password, and never runs. (I ran the command above manually, that's how I found out).

How exactly do I use `flock`? Do I type a variable in my script that injects the sudo password when `flock` asks for it? (I know it's not secure, so there must be a different way to do this).

I tried to research this subject but couldn't find any good answers that explain how to use it properly.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to put your script in root's cronjob.

Comment: which command is requiring `sudo`? `flock` or `script.sh`? if the latter, how are you currently running the script in cron without `flock`? have you tried a web search on `run cronjob with sudo permissions`? one possible solution: [this Q&A @ superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1491794)

Comment: @Cyrus I guess that could work

Comment: @markp-fuso `flock` requires sudo because of accessing `/var` path. My script runs fine by itself without sudo.

Comment: move the lockfile to a directory that does not require sudo access?

Comment: Out of curiosity (and because I've seen soooo many X<->Y problems): what are you backing up with that script, and could you e.g. solve the problem by using inotifywait and shuffling files immediately after a WRITE_CLOSE?

Comment: @markp-fuso i thought the lock file had to be in the `/var/lock` directory.

Comment: @tink My rsync script clones/mirrors my data drive daily. The rclone script syncs specific directories to cloud accounts. I don't know what inotifywait and WRITE_CLOSE are. I'll do some research on those 2...

Comment: the lock file just needs to be somewhere your cronjob can access it, eg, `/path/to/rclone/myjob.lock`

Comment: @Marslander - inotify is a kernel-framework that monitors file-system level events. `inotifywait` is a command-line tool that allows you to monitor files/directories from userland. A `WRITE_CLOSE` in inotify terminology is an event where a write to a file gets done and then file then gets closed, i.e. it was changed and is now saved. In other words, when a file gets changed or created you can do something ... caveat: this will *not* recurse into newly created directories.

Comment: @tink Thank you for the explanation. Off topic: I feel like one of these solutions should be posted as the answer. Just a thought. we can't just stay in the comment section... lol

Comment: @Marslander you're welcome to create an answer and describe what step(s) you took to address your issue

Comment: There are several good examples on how to use flock in the flock manual. see `man flock`